# Symfony 1.4 Criteria addGroupByColumn then order by most

Tags: symfony, sql-order-by, symfony-1.4

I use symfony 1.4 and I want to group some data, order it by grouped columns then select the one who has the most records.
My code looks like this:

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->addGroupByColumn(MetricPeer::POST_TYPE_ID);
$c->addDescendingOrderByColumn(MetricPeer::POST_TYPE_ID);    
$posts = MetricPeer::doSelectOne($c);
```

I know that line "$c->addDescendingOrderByColumn(MetricPeer::POST_TYPE_ID);" it is ordering data just by the numbers and it is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static function topPosts($limit,$source_id,$interval1,$interval2,$con = null) {
    if($con === null) $con = Propel::getConnection(self::DATABASE_NAME);
    $sql = "SELECT *, COUNT(post_id) AS value_occurrence FROM metric WHERE source_id LIKE ".$source_id." AND visit_out BETWEEN '".$interval1."' AND  '".$interval2."' GROUP BY post_id ORDER BY value_occurrence DESC LIMIT ".$limit."";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();       
    $topreads = MetricPeer::populateObjects($stmt);
    return $topreads;
}
```

This is my humble solution for now, I thought it might be useful for others, too.
Thank you.